# Can Paypal rest api get access to personal account data?

Tags: rest, paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox

I have two sandbox Paypal accounts, one of them is '**Business**' and the other is '**Personal**', and finally one real Paypal account.

I've created an app with my '**Business**' account, and I've used the app (id,secret) to obtain an access token, and with this access token I am able to access the information of my '**Business**' account.

Question is:

How can I let the app access other '**Personal**' accounts' information?

(i.e. Just like Google Drive or Dropbox when using OAuth to let the account owner give my app the permission to access his files, So one app has an access tokens for multiple accounts)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Permission Service

[Permissions Service Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/)

[Permissions Service Getting Started Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/gs_PermissionsService/)